# What are the rules regarding recursion in Vim mappings?

Tags: vim, recursion, mapping

I have a question in two parts about vim mappings, e.g., imap, and recursion. In Vim, mappings can be either right-recursive or neither left- nor right-recursive, but they are not allowed to be left-recursive, right? Why not? I tested the following examples to illustrate what I mean:

1. (left recursive) When I execute

   ```
   :imap x xyz
   ```

   then type "x" in insert mode, what is input into the buffer is

   ```
   xyz
   ```

   As far as I can tell, this behavior is indistinguishable from what would happen had I used inoremap instead of imap.
2. (neither left nor right recursive) When I execute

   ```
   :imap x yxz
   ```

   then type "x" in insert mode, what is (attempted to be) put in the buffer is

   ```
   y...yz
   ```
3. (right recursive) When I execute

   ```
   :imap x yzx
   ```

   then type "x" in insert mode, what is (attempted to be) put in the buffer is

   ```
   yzyzyzyzyzyz...
   ```
4. (mutually recursive) When I execute

   ```
   :imap x abc
   :imap a x
   ```

   then type "x" in insert mode, I receive "E223: recursive mapping".

It seems that I've demonstrated that Vim disallows left-recursive mappings and mutually recursive mappings, but I'd like to verify: **What are the rules for defining (possibly mutually) recursive mappings in Vim?**

Comment: But...why?! The only valid use of recursive mappings is to have it apply until it errors out at the end of the buffer.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, why not? Vim allows it, so I wanted to know how they work. Are you certain that the use case you give is the *only* valid use of (possibly mutually) recursive mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Recursive_mappings and the vim command

```
:help recursive_mapping

If you include the {lhs} in the {rhs} you have a recursive mapping.  When
{lhs} is typed, it will be replaced with {rhs}.  When the {lhs} which is
included in {rhs} is encountered it will be replaced with {rhs}, and so on.
This makes it possible to repeat a command an infinite number of times ...
There is one exception: If the {rhs} starts with {lhs}, the first character
is not mapped again (this is Vi compatible) ... For example, if you use:

:map x y
:map y x

Vim will replace x with y, and then y with x, etc.
When this has happened 'maxmapdepth' times (default 1000),
Vim will give the error message "recursive mapping".
```

It seems that the documentation only concerns itself with mappings where the {lhs} is a single character, but the behavior is still observed when the {lhs} is more than one character and is a prefix of the {rhs}.

Comment: In the last paragraph, shouldn't {lhs} and {rhs} be interchanged?